# Messages not in SQS queue when processing lambda is linked

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS FIFO queue that gets populated from selections made on my webpage.  I also have a lambda function that's supposed to process and delete the messages from my queue.  I set it up so that my SQS queue is an event trigger for my lambda function.  However, when I did this I stopped seeing my queue's message count increase whenever selections are made from my webpage.  Below is my queue's details which is the default.
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCcAN.png)

Comment: Are you not seeing that there are messages being sent to the queue, or just that the number is zero when you look at the count? By triggering a Lambda from the queue the messages that are processed by the function will be deleted from the queue.

Comment: The message count is always zero.  But when I increase the Receive Message Wait Count from 0 (10 seconds for example), I do see the Message count increase, as well with the 'Message In Flight' count for multiple selections sent from the web page.  However, they stay the way they are until I invoke the lambda function (process & delete) from the lambda code.  This might be a separate issue though.

Comment: If your Lambda is triggered by the SQS queue it is running whenever there are messages in the queue. You don't have to run it, it's being run automatically. The reason you see the count go up when you increase the wait is because Lambda is waiting.